# Get a count of dates by group in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, pandas-groupby

```
Date    Latitude    Longitude   Disaster
2011-01-10  56.79   89.90   Cyclonic Flood
2011-02-09  56.79   89.90   Cyclonic Flood
2010-11-20  34.08   69.92   Cyclonic Flood
2011-01-10  56.79   89.90   Earthquake
2010-12-19  67.78   155.35  Earthqauke
2010-12-19  66.78   125.35  Cyclonic Flood
2010-12-19  66.78   125.35  Earthqauke
2017-09-10  56.99   98.22   Cyclonic Flood
2017-09-10  56.99   98.22   Cyclonic Flood
```

The column `Date` is of type date and I am new to time series related problems which is therefore causing me some trouble with a task wherein I need to first, group by `Latitude` and `Longitude` and then  *count of how many days (dates) there were where earthquakes occurred in the region.* I tried using -

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])['Disaster'].count())
```

Can anyone confirm or help me correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataset contains more than one type of disaster per latitude / longitude, your attempted code would count all disaster dates (not just earthquakes).

In order to count just earthquake dates, you could filter your `DataFrame` and then `DataFrame.groupby().count()`. Here is one way along with some modification to the data in your "Disaster" column to illustrate why it would be important if your data contains more than one type of disaster:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['2011-01-10', 56.79, 89.90, 'Earthquake'],
    ['2011-02-09', 56.79, 89.90, 'Earthquake'],
    ['2010-11-20', 34.08, 69.92, 'Cyclonic Flood'],
    ['2010-12-19', 66.78, 125.35, 'Earthquake'],
    ['2017-09-10', 56.99, 98.22, 'Cyclonic Flood'],
    ['2017-09-10', 56.99, 98.22, 'Earthquake'],
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Disaster'])

# filter the DataFrame, then group and count
filtered = df[df.Disaster == 'Earthquake']
grouped = filtered.groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Disaster']).count()

print(grouped)
# OUTPUT
#                                Date
# Latitude Longitude Disaster        
# 56.79    89.90     Earthquake     2
# 56.99    98.22     Earthquake     1
# 66.78    125.35    Earthquake     1
```